# Clone a row in JSP table having drop-down from MYSQL DB and display data (from DB) related to the option selected in drop-down in each respective row

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, jsp

**ISSUE:** 
I am trying to generate a invoice in JSP. Where I am selecting values of item name from drop down. Drop down values are from database, On change of select tag I want to display the values associate to that item name from database(item price, HSN code, tax, description of item etc.). This is working for first row in table But when we are adding new row(by cloning row) we are unable perform on change function hence the related data is not displayed.

I have tried the below codes on my own. But couldn't get the desired result.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/leftstick/DVEXG/
http://www.iamrohit.in/add-remove-table-rows-dynamically/
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-append-and-remove-table-row-dynamically
http://jsfiddle.net/HjZkB/2/
http://jsfiddle.net/Dz24f/
https://youtu.be/KnKMGCSPj3Y
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVSfp8yT8lA&feature=youtu.be
```

**I added database connection to below code but did not gave me the desired result.**

```
<%@ page import = "java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Add / Remove Table Rows Dynamically</title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var j=1;
    $("#table-data").on('click', 'input.addButton', function() {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

        var allTrs = $tr.closest('table').find('tr');
        var lastTr = allTrs[allTrs.length-1];
        var $clone = $(lastTr).clone();
        $clone.find('td').each(function(){
            var el = $(this).find(':first-child');
            var r1= $(this).find(':first');
            var idr= r1.attr('id') || null;
            var id = el.attr('id') || null;

            if(id) {
                var i = id.substr(id.length-1);
                var prefix = id.substr(0, (id.length-1));
                el.attr('id', prefix+(+i+1));
                el.attr('name', prefix+(+i+1));
                   }            
        });

        $clone.find('input:text').val('');
        $tr.closest('table').append($clone);

    });
    //var i=1;
    $("#table-data").on('change', 'select', function(){        
        var value = $(this).val();
        //var row1 = $(this).closest('table').find(' tbody tr:eq(0)').attr('id');       alert(row1);
        var rid=$(this).closest('tr').attr("id");       alert(rid);
        //var i=1;
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text').each(function(){
            $.get("myinvoice.jsp",{q:value},function(data){
                //rid.val(data);        
                //$("#javaquery'"+i+"'").html(data);
            //rid++;
                 $("#javaquery1").html(data);
                $("#table-data option[value='"+value+"']").prop('selected', true);
                });         
            });                 //each
        });                     //select change
    });                         // ready function
    //});
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="table-data">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>SelectOne</td>
        <td>TextBox</td>
        <td>TextBox</td>
        <td>Add</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr id="javaquery1">
        <td>

         <%
   String desc = "";
    String price= "";
  // String q =request.getParameter("q");   System.out.println("q = "+q);
   try {
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","root1216");
        Statement smt = con.createStatement(); //Create Statement to inte000ract
        ResultSet r = smt.executeQuery("select item_name from item"); %>

        <select name="Id.0" class="dropdn" id="Id.0" ><option value="">--Select--</option>
        <%
        while(r.next())
        {%>

     <option value="<%=r.getString("item_name")%>"> <%=r.getString("item_name")%> </option>

     <% }  %>
       </select> 

       <br>
        <%
        Statement s=con.createStatement();
        String q =request.getParameter("q");    System.out.println("q = "+q);
        ResultSet r1=s.executeQuery("select * from item where(item_name='"+q+"');");
        while (r1.next()) {
         desc = r1.getString("item_description");
         price=r1.getString("item_price"); System.out.println("price = "+price);
         }
        %>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="Integer1.0" name="Integer1.0" value='<%= price %>'/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="Integer2.0" name="Integer2.0" value='<%= desc %>'/></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="addButton" value="Add" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <% 
        con.close();
   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
%>      
</table>
</body> 
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpvFC.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GRkt.jpg)

Comment: That's a little vague

Comment: @Strawberry, isn't the question not understandable ? Shall I add some more specific information ?